# Rails - how to add multiple bookings for same user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an events app using Rails. At the moment the booking process only allows for one user to book one place per booking. I need to add the facility whereby a User can make multiple/group bookings at once. So, not only do I need a 'quantity' function I also need this to tally with the price. I've trawled SO and Google trying to find the answers but have gotten nowhere for something which is pretty common for most sites.

I assume I need a method of some kind (in the model?) -

```
  def total_amount
    @booking.quantity * @event.price
end
```

So, if someone wants to book for 10 spaces on an event which costs £10 per space then the total amount should tally to £100.

Do I use methods in my model/controller or do I need some javascript for the process of reflecting the price per group booking?

Here's the MVC code for the bookings -

**Booking.rb**

```
     class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user





end
```

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
    class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
        #@total_amount = @booking_quantity.to_f * @event_price.to_f

    end




 def create
        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

        Booking.transaction do

            @event.reload
            if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
            flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
            end 
        end




        if @booking.save

            # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
            # #{} == puts a variable into a string
            Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
                card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end

        if @event.is_free?

            @booking.save!
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        end
    end



    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
    end



end
```

**new.html.erb (bookings)**

```
                <% if @event.is_free? %>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Your Booking Confirmation</h2>
        </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                        <h1>Hi there</h1>

                        <p>You have placed a booking on <%= @event.title %></p>

                        <p>Your order number is <%= @booking.id %></p>

                        <p>We hope you have a wonderful time. Enjoy!</p>

                        <p>Love from Mama Knows Best</p>
                </div>        
                  <div class="panel-footer">
                    <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
                  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>                      

                <% else %>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>

            <div class="panel-body">    

                <p>Total Amount<%= @event.price %></p>
                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>





                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#new_booking');

    if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="booking[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };

  // jQuery(function($)  { - changed to the line below
  $(document).on("ready page:load", function () {

    $('#new_booking').submit(function(event) {
      var $form = $(this);

      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

      // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the schema for bookings and events -

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "event_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "stripe_token"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
t.integer  "quantity"
   end   

create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.string   "location"
t.date     "date"
t.time     "time"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "organised_by"
t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.integer  "category_id"
t.string   "url"
t.integer  "number_of_spaces"
t.integer  "price"
t.boolean  "is_free"
t.integer  "price_cents",        default: 0,     null: false
t.integer  "price_pennies",      default: 0,     null: false
t.string   "price_currency",     default: "GBP", null: false
t.boolean  "happened",           default: false
  end
```

I think, ideally, I need a supplementary partial form activated when a user clicks on 'Book the Event' which asks them to specify the number of spaces they wish to book for the event BEFORE proceeding to payment. Any assistance or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a virtual attribute (as you suggested) in the model Booking with the total price is a good way.

**booking.rb**:

```
def total_amount
  self.quantity * self.event.price
end
```

Let the user specify the number of the spaces before he sees the confirmation page (at least, for a better UX). Set default to 1. Transfer the number of spaces to the 'new' method:

```
def new
  ....
  @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
  ....

end
```

Now you can display or access the total price with

```
<p>Total Amount<%= @booking.total_amount %></p>
```

Comment: So, do I build a supplementary partial or include this all in the payment form? Would that even work?

Comment: You don't need a partial. Think of total_price as a regular attribute. It must work

Comment: Where should I let the user specify the number of spaces, though, on the new.html form above? Do I just include an input form?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ooqng73L/
Put this field on the event page. It's common practice on the booking sites.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting 'undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass' error in relation to the total_amount model method above. Does it not recognise this?

Comment: I've changed the method to include to_i for the quantity and price but whilst this removes the error it isn't stating any price when I get to the payment page. There's a 0(zero) where the amount should be.

Comment: Try to test it in `rails c`. Post your form and params which executes your `new` method